# Selecting value through other table Postgresql with three foreign keys

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I can't figure it out how to get into other tables with multiple foreign keys. 
I got 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE product 
  ( 
     id      SERIAL NOT NULL, 
     image   text, 
     PRIMARY KEY (id) 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE spin_result 
  ( 
    id              SERIAL NOT NULL,
    first_slot      INT NOT NULL, 
    second_slot     INT NOT NULL, 
    third_slot      INT NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (first_slot) REFERENCES product(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (second_slot) REFERENCES product(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (third_slot) REFERENCES product(id)
  );
```

I want to get this output:

```
|spin_result.id|first_slot.image|second_slot.image|third_slot.image|
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT s_r.id, 
  p.image as "first_slot", 
  p.image AS "second_slot",
  p.image AS "third_slot"
FROM spin_result s_r, product p
WHERE s_r.first_slot = p.id 
  AND s_r.second_slot = p.id 
  AND s_r.third_slot = p.id;
```

Comment: Just use three joins. As simple as that.

Comment: Your spin_result table should have a `product_id`. Also instead of using 3 columns, why not just have a single `slot` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the `product` table three times, one per foreign key, as in:

```
SELECT 
    s_r.id, 
    p1.image as "first_slot", 
    p2.image AS "second_slot", 
    p3.image AS "third_slot"
  FROM spin_result s_r
  JOIN product p1 on p1.id = s_r.first_slot
  JOIN product p2 on p2.id = s_r.second_slot
  JOIN product p3 on p3.id = s_r.third_slot
```

You can join the same table as many times as you want, as long as you use different aliases.